# Symfony COM class

Tags: php, com, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to use COM (Component Object Model, http://php.net/manual/en/intro.com.php) class in symfony3.

```
namespace AppBundle\Lib;
class Sfera
{
    /**
     * Sfera constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $gt = new COM("Insert.gt") or die("Cannot create an InsERT GT object");
//        $gt = new \COM("Insert.gt") or die("Cannot create an InsERT GT object");

    }
}
```

But i cannot find COM class in symfony.

> Attempted to load class "COM" from namespace "AppBundle\Lib". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

or

> Attempted to load class "COM" from the global namespace. Did you
>   forget a "use" statement?

I enabled php_com_dotnet.dll in php.ini

How to get it working?

Comment: My bad, its working now. Extension php_com_dotnet.dll file was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

When you use namespaces in your class then all `root` classes need to have `\` before name. This will work:

```
namespace AppBundle\Lib;

class Sfera
{
    /**
     * Sfera constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $gt = new \COM("Insert.gt") or die("Cannot create an InsERT GT object");

    }
}
```

More about namespaces in php is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Also make sure that extension is enabled - check if it's visible in `phpinfo();` output. Maybe you forgot to set `enable_dl = On` or uncomment `extension_dir = "ext"`?